# Curve for similar triangles

Tags: geometry, recreational-mathematics

Inspired by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2746548/find-the-two-missing-angles-in-a-quadrilateral) I began thinking about the following:

[image]

Given a quadrilateral ABCD where $\triangle ABC$ is a fixed isosceles triangle and D is free to move, where can D be placed such that $\triangle AED$ is similar to $\triangle ADC$? The figure above gives an example of such a position.

Using trial and error (iteration) I was able to map out such positions:

[image]

As you can see, the positions turn out to give a rather nice (half) heart shaped curve.

My question is: Can anyone work out what the equation of this curve is?

Comment: Did you try putting $D$ inside $△ABC$? I'm thinking it's a cardiod.

Comment: @Christopher: Putting D inside the triangle means $\triangle AED$ disappears.

Comment: Hence, clearly the curve only exists for $x \ge 6$. The curve isn't a function, so finding a relation may be harder than normal.

Comment: When $D$ is inside $\triangle ABC$, the line segment $BD$ won't intersect $AC$ but the line $BD$ still does. What's wrong with putting $D$ at $(2,0)$, for example?

Comment: @Landuros What does $x \geq 6$ mean? And as far as your comment goes, it is not a function $y = f(x)$, but it is definetely a function $r = f(\theta)$ where $\theta = \angle CDB$ and $r = BD$, so polar coordinates seems to be the way to go here.

Comment: @nickgard: Yes, I could use the line $BD$ to intersect $AC$ but this wouldn't give me two similar triangles. Which is kinda the premise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your picture from above, set $2k = \overline{AC}$, $h = \textrm{dist}(B, AC)$, and $\theta = \angle AED$.

For fixed $k, h, \theta$, there clearly is a unique point $D$ such that the two triangles $\triangle AED$ and $\triangle ADC$ are similar.

Set $a := \overline{AE} = k - h\cot(\theta), s := \overline{DE}$.
By the cosine law, $\overline{AD}^2 = a^2 + s^2 - 2as\cos(\theta)$. Also, similarity says that $$\frac{\overline{AE}}{\overline{AD}} = \frac{\overline{AD}}{\overline{AC}},$$
or $a^2 + s^2 - 2 as \cos(\theta) = 2ak$, so that

\begin{align*}
s &= a \cos(\theta) + \sqrt{ a^2\cos^2(\theta) + a(2k-a)}\\ &= (k - h \cot(\theta))\cos(\theta) + \sqrt{(k - h \cot(\theta))^2\cos^2(\theta) + k^2 - h^2 \cot^2(\theta)}
\end{align*}

Unfortunately, there seems to be no simpler expression for $s$ (that I could find, at least). In any case, we now have a closed form expression for $D$ in polar coordinates by centering at $B$ and noting that
$$r := \overline{BD} = \frac{h}{\sin(\theta)} + s.$$

Hope this helps (but I don't think this would look like a cardioid in general).

Comment: Nice. I could follow your derivation up until the last equation. After some thinking, it seems to me you need to change the definition of $\theta $ so it is also centered at $B$. I.e. $\theta$ should generally become $\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta$. And shouldn't the last equation be $r=\frac{h}{cos(\theta)}+s$?

Comment: @Jens You're right about the last bit, it should be $\frac{h}{\sin(\theta)}$. I've edited the answer.
As for the choice of $\theta$, it's a matter of mirroring and/or rotating, it shouldn't change anything fundamental. In any case, if you want to change to $\pi/2 - \theta$, I believe you can use the last equation and use some of the basic trigonometric relations to get the final expression, right?

Comment: True, but it would be nice if you made the necessary changes in your answer as well. Anyway, after making the changes, I was able to plot the resulting graph on Desmos. I think I'll add an answer just to show the plot. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using the answer of @Pedro M as my basis, I was able to plot the following curve in Desmos:

[image]

The blue line is at $X=6$. Still a lovely half-heart.